# Return not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an `$.ajax` callback, I want to do something depending on what I receive from the server, which is sending `true` or `false`.

The problem is, somewhere in the code, I want a return to fire and it doesn't :

```
function check()
{
    // $.ajax callback(result)
    {
        console.log(result); //in this case I get 'true' (boolean)
        if(!result)
        {
            // I checked I don't end up here
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('well done'); // shows up in the console
            return "done";
        }
    }
    return "oops";
}

// later in the code
console.log(check()); // displays "oops" whereas the console.log('well done') has showned up in the console
```

Parts of the function I didn't give you are mostly CSS effects.

Do you have any idea why a `return` couldn't fire, or what did I miss ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's not really clear from the code, but the return probably doesn't return because ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: @adeneo I just checked, and the `async` parameter is set to `false`

Comment: That's even worse, never use synchronous ajax.

Comment: @adeneo Oh I didn't know that. Can you tell me why ? Also, setting the `async` to `true` make the returns fire too late (the console displays `undefined`). how should I do ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @adaneo Well I learnt something today ^^ Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a value in a callback, this is why you don't get this value, your code is equivalent to:

```
function callback (result) {
    if (!result) { }
    else {
        console.log('well done') ;
        return "done";
    }
}

function _ajax (cb) {
    cb (true) ; // Call cb but does not care about the result
    return true ;
}

function check() {
    ajax (callback) ; // Call ajax but does not care about its result
    return "oops";
}

check () ;
```

If you were doing an asynchronous request, the behaviour would be a bit different, but the idea would remain the same.

---

**You should never do synchronous (a)jax calls**, but if you did not care, you could do the following:

```
function check () {
    var res ;
    $.ajax ({
        success: function (result) {
            if (!result) { res = "fail" ; }
            else {
                console.log('well done') ;
                res = "done" ;
            }
        }
    }) ;
    return (typeof res === 'undefined') ? "oops" : res ;
}
```